# Unable to move the control from parent to child window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have two windows default, working on second window. Here I have clicked on some link which opens another window. Now I am trying to shift my focus to this opened window, but unable to focus it. 
Initially I have taken `Set <String> obj1=driver.getWindowHandles();` which have two values. After clicking on link I have taken another set as `Set <String> obj2=driver.getWindowHandles();`

In the for each loop I am adding the strings of the obj2 to obj1, if the obj2 is added then I am writing the code line as `driver.switchTo().window(obj2-- which is added)` but I am getting error like this..

```
"Error message: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:webview
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.65)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.7.236900,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you try debugging this?  Is the newest window handle actually being passed to the switchTo method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I have never faced this issue, it seems familiar. I saw this error message returned on one of my friend's test script. I then searched and found the following links

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765847/unknown-error-devtools-returned-unknown-typewebvie)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359621/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-devtools-returned-unknown-typeservi)

My friend's issue got resolved after he followed advice given in 2. You can try the resolutions mentioned.

Comment: Yes this error is due to version problem mostly, because it works with FF browser. I haven't checked with chrome browser because I need to downgrade the version.

Answer (score 0):

This is due an old ChromeDriver version, check and update the ChromeDriver to the newest version here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.19/